Are passed structlog loggers process-safe?
I want to use structlog in a multiprocess application in python. The processes shall be able to log as well. Hence I need to ensure that writes to any I/O are process-safe.
Python standard logging should only be thread-safe and with this question I am exploring whether structlog is as well?
So far I have decided to configure structlog in combination with the standard Python logging as per the docs.
My configuration is performed by this function
import logging.config
import sys
from typing import IO

import structlog

from logging import DEBUG


def configure_structured_logging(
        console_stream: IO[str] = sys.stdout
):
    """
    Configures the standard logging to log the given IO stream.
    If called without parameters this will only configure output to sys.stdout.

    @param console_stream: The stream to output the live console logs to.
    """
    min_log_level = DEBUG

    # TODO: Patch the timezone into the timestamper
    timestamper_no_tz = structlog.processors.TimeStamper(
        fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f", utc=False
    )

    structlog.configure(
        processors=[
            structlog.contextvars.merge_contextvars,
            structlog.processors.add_log_level,
            structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
            structlog.dev.set_exc_info,
            timestamper_no_tz,
            structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter.wrap_for_formatter,
        ],
        context_class=dict,
        logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
        wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger,
        cache_logger_on_first_use=False,
    )

    pre_formatter_chain = [
        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
        structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
    ]

    # std logging configuration dict
    formatters = {
        "console": {
            "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            "foreign_pre_chain": pre_formatter_chain,
            "processors": [
                timestamper_no_tz,
                structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter.remove_processors_meta,
                structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer(
                    colors=True,
                    force_colors=True,
                    exception_formatter=structlog.dev.plain_traceback
                ),
            ],
        },
    }

    handlers = {
        "console_handler": {
            "()": logging.StreamHandler,
            "level": min_log_level,
            "formatter": "console",
            "stream": console_stream,
        },
    }

    logging_config = {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "formatters": formatters,
        "handlers": handlers,
        "loggers": {
            "root": {"level": min_log_level, "handlers": list(handlers.keys())}
        },
    }

    logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)

In a nutshell, this configures the Python standard logging to use structlog formatters and output to sys.stdout.
Now to the juicy part: Is this setup process-safe?
As a note: I am on Python 3.9.18. To my knowledge the Python standard logging is thread-safe but not process-safe (see logging module source). The only mention of multiprocessing in the structlog docs is here and is regarding the pickleability of a logger. As far as I have looked through the structlog source code I could not find anything it would consider thread- or process-safety. In my setup this also would not be its job, but the job of the standard logging handlers.
To verify this, I created a minimal example.
It consists of a simple worker which is provided a structlog logger.
Through this logger it logs 1000 info messages.
Trough a multiprocessing.Pool I spawn 1000 of those workers.
Without process-safety this should IMO result in malformed console output.
It does however work without a problem. Every row of the log is perfectly fine.
I tried the same while logging to a file and that also worked flawlessly.
The minimal example using the above configuration function:
import sys
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

from structlog import get_logger

from structlog_config import configure_structured_logging

configure_structured_logging(console_stream=sys.stdout)
logger = get_logger(module_level="playground")

# A worker provided with a logger
def worker(count, local_logger):
    pid = os.getpid()
    for i in range(count):
        local_logger.info("This is logging %s for TEST", str(i), pid=pid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_count = 1000
    proc_count = 1000
    pool = Pool(proc_count)
    inputs = [(log_count, logger)]*proc_count
    pool.starmap(worker, inputs)

I feel like I am missing something here. I need to make sure that this does not break and while this test is nice and all, I would like to understand how there are no race conditions. As a little side note, I also experimented with cache_logger_on_first_use being set to True, which according to the (aforementioned) docs would make the loggers unpickleable. However my example still works fine with this option set. Is this information deprecated?
P.S.: I know I can configure this setup to use QueueHandler and definitely be process-safe, however I have decided that if I have to pass around a Queue anyway, I might as well leverage the benefits of structlog and pass around the loggers themselves.

Given your configuration, structlog plays no role in output whatsoever. It only calls the standard library's output functions.
In other words, your question can be simplified to:

Is it safe to use logging.StreamHandler to concurrently log to standard out?

I'm fairly sure it is, but it's more complicated when logging into files (which I would discourage).

Yes, you are right. I noticed that later as well. I found the article you provided earlier and integrated it into the setup. This made the overall approach rather complex, but I might do a write-up once I smoothed out all the kinks. Thank you, by the way, for the nicely structured code. It was very easy to expand and adapt the behavior of the classes cleanly.
